# In a plugin, how to add a html page to ckeditor dialog

Tags: asp.net, plugins, dialog, ckeditor

I'm working on upgrading a old fckeditor to ckeditorv3. I found most of APIs been updated.
There is a internal used plugin ,its content is a aspx page,and this page will provide dynmic list.
I want to upgrade that plugin to make it work in new ckeditorv3.

Can anyone show me a tutorial link about how to add a html page to a ckedirot dialog ?

I found that one http://www.kusog.org/articles/OtherJavaScriptLibraries_WritingCustomCKEditorPlugins/ , but it is just some basic info. What i want to do is embed a html page into a plugin's dialog.

Comment: "new ckeditorv3" - latest CKEditor is v4 ;)

Comment: I need embed it into a asp.net site in which a .net dll will make my life easy. But currently only v3 coming with a .net dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.  You need to load the page in a dialog iframe.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('customfields',
{
    init: function(editor) {
        editor.addCommand('customfields', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('customfields'));
        editor.ui.addButton('Customfields',
        {
            label: 'Custom Fields',
            command: 'customfields',
            icon: this.path + 'CustomFields.gif'
        });

        CKEDITOR.dialog.addIframe(
            'customfields',
            'Custom Fields',
            this.path + 'CustomFields2.aspx', null, null,
            function() { alert('aaaa'); }, function() { alert('bbbb'); }
        );
    }
});
```